# Android logic for login with a token. Am I right?

Tags: android

I need to perform login against a REST API webservice.

I POST username/password and, if they are right, webserver returns a me a token, to use for every call.

I'm going to save this token in EXTRA, and recall the EXTRA from every intent that I will call. Am I right? Or I need to use the `sharedPreferences` ?

Thank you

Comment: It's completely up to you how you want to store that token. You can pass it around to the activities that might need it, you can save it in SharedPreferences, you could create a global configuration object that holds the token, ...

Comment: Do you have remember me in login screen?

Comment: Well you can either create an account authenticator (like in a sync adapter), or just store it in shared preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how you want to store that token.

- `SharedPreferences` writes to internal storage.
- A Singleton or similar would keep that token alive in memory, but won't be kept across instances of your application.
- Same for EXTRA as Singleton.

Best practice would be IMHO to keep the token in memory and request a new one at each startup of your application, for safety.

Comment: I think the key element is here. Unless you want to keep a perpetual session do not write the token to internal storage, use what ever pattern you wish to keep it alive for the duration of the session but in volatile state by definition.

Answer (score 0):

In this example they, as far as I understand, do something like this:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git

1) Upon app start request the token and save it in Preferences

2) Make calls using this token until server refuses the token

3) Request a new token upon server refusal